# How to actually disable the remote shell?

Tags: shell, neo4j

I'm trying to simultaneously launch 2 Neo4j 1.9 instances on the same host (1 for dev and 1 for test). I had realized it was not enough to vary HTTP and HTTPS ports because the remote shell has its own port (1337 by default).

The second instance cannot start because it cannot bind.

```
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1337; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:328)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:236)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:207)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:122)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:108)
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:203)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RmiLocation.ensureRegistryCreated(RmiLocation.java:180)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RmiLocation.bind(RmiLocation.java:195)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemotelyAvailableServer.makeRemotelyAvailable(RemotelyAvailableServer.java:99)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractServer.makeRemotelyAvailable(AbstractServer.java:156)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.ShellBootstrap.enable(ShellBootstrap.java:122)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.ShellBootstrap.load(ShellBootstrap.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.ShellServerKernelExtension.start(ShellServerKernelExtension.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:492)
    ... 12 more

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:349)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:667)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:317)
    ... 27 more
```

I tried to disable the remote shell as specified in [the official Neo4j documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9/shell-starting.html). By adding **enable_remote_shell = false** in **neoj-server.properties**. But it does not work.

What's the right way to disable this (optional?) Neo4j service ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have put it in the wrong place. Put `enable_remote_shell = false` in `neo4j.properties`

Comment: I'll try to put the parameter in neo4j.properties instead of neo4j-server.properties but the doc talks about modifying the server configuration that goes into neo4j-server.properties...

Comment: Thx Nicholas. That was it. As soon as I moved the parameters to neo4j.properties, it did the right thing. BTW, I added a comment on the page of the official documentation about this detail. Apparently, the (remote) shell extension does not care about neo4j-server.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Why not give it different port?

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell-starting.html

Comment: It works... as long as you put the new port in the right configuration file. In neo4j.properties but not in neo4j-server.properties.

Answer (score 0):

You may go to `conf/neo4j-server.properties` and change the following property like this

```
# To disable all shells:
org.neo4j.server.manage.console_engines=
```

Look @
[Disabling console types in Webadmin](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-configuration.html#_other_configuration_options)

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but I need the shell in local mode

Comment: What do you mean with shell in local mode??

Comment: I mean being able to run commands through the WebAdmin console tab, in Cypher mode. I may be wrong but I thought it requires the shell service too.