# Unable to use neo4j-shell remotely

Tags: neo4j

I am unable to use neo4j-shell to connect remotely to a server. Here's what happens:

```
amy@wombat$ neo4j-shell -host myserver.mycompany.com -port 1337
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (0)$ help
Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
neo4j-sh (0)$
```

I am running:
neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64)

I am able to telnet into this server on port 1337. I am also able to run neo4j-shell on the server itself.

I have read [neo4j-shell "connection refused" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867635/neo4j-shell-connection-refused-error), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413094/neo4j-remote-connection-refused, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896654/neo4j-remoteclient-cant-get-a-connection, however none of them helped.

The [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/shell-starting.html#shell-enabling-remote) seems to suggest that this should go into neo4j-server.properties. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280285/how-to-actually-disable-the-remote-shell) indicates that it should go into neo4j.properties. I put it in both, but it's still not working.
enable_remote_shell = true

Comment: can you please paste your `/etc/hosts` ? 127.0.1.1 sound suspicous.

Comment: That was the problem! I had a typo in the /etc/hosts file on the client.

Comment: Please fine the solution posted in a linke below

http://superuser.com/questions/788733/neo4j-shell-connection-refused-on-aws